# Angular 8: max-height attribute for a material dialog is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I am working on a project in angular 8, where I have used a MatDialog to open new component with form inputs in a dialog. For example:

```
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';

import {AddDialogComponent} from '../add-dialog.component';

constructor(private dialog: MatDialog){
}

private addNewRow() {

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddDialogComponent, {

      width: 'auto',
      height: 'auto',
      maxHeight: '100vh',
      maxWidth:'100vw',
      data: Data
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      result => {

         // statements
      });
  }
```

Here when dialog get open, **maxWidth: '100vw'** works fine where as **maxHeight: '100vh'** is not supported. Also tried **maxHeight: '100vh !important'** and tried change style from .css file.

Both didn't work. Any suggestions or solution for this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

It's because the `.mat-dialog-content` has a `max-height: 65vh`. You can either decide not to use the directive, or override this in your css:

```
.mat-dialog-content {
  max-height: initial;
}
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cbsatw?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html)

Comment: I am aware of it. After all I have also did the changes you mentioned. But need to make "max-height" work for **.mat-dialog-container**.

Answer (score 2):

actually in the upper version of angular material this style work for me

```
.mat-mdc-dialog-content {
  max-height: unset;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

API suggests that a number or a string is fine inside `maxWidth` or `maxHeight`...

But we can use `::ng-deep` would help when putting this inside CSS... Note that the rendered `.cdk-overlay-pane` has an inline max-width of 80%, so we had to use `100% !important` otherwise, we are able to do this via CSS

**relevant CSS**:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane { max-width: 100vw !important; max-height: 100vh; }
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-dialog-container{
  background-color:lightgreen;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-dialog-container .mat-dialog-content { max-height: 100%; }
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwnovo)

Comment: Except **"max-height"**, all other attribute works. Try adding more text/contents inside **<div mat-dialog-content> </div>** in your example. scrollbar appears to scroll up down, but the height doesn't go to max-height(100vh).

Comment: Hey @Pujan, try this css `::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane { max-width: 100vw !important; max-height: 100vh; }
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-dialog-container{
  background-color:lightgreen;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-pane .mat-dialog-container .mat-dialog-content { max-height: 100%; }` which is also updated on the stackblitz link...

Answer (score -4):

When opening dialog you can provide properties following way and it will open dialog in full screen

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(exampleDialog, {
  height: '100vh',
  width: '100vw',
  maxHeight: '100vh',
  maxWidth: '100vw',
});
```

Comment: Downvoting this because these properties don't affect the max height of the actual content, just the dialog window itself.